# Can "concerning" ever be used to mean "worthy of concern"?

Tags: meaning

My daughter said "These photographs are concerning".  Her intention was to convey that they were disconcerting, or alarming in some way.  My impulse was to correct her, but then I doubted myself and thought that perhaps this is a legitimate use of the word.  The two online dictionaries I looked in don't have secondary definition that fits the bill, so, I'm now once again reasonably certain that my impulse was correct, but I'd be curious what you folks think.

Comment: Little as I like it, it has *become* a common use, and one to which no reasonable exception can be taken. [grump grump]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the OED’s definitions of the adjective *concerning* is

> That gives cause for anxiety or distress.

That would seem to cover your daughter’s use. Whether using the word in this way is an effective means of expressing her meaning is another matter.

Comment: This meaning, while rarer than the meaning ‘regarding’, is quite simply derived from the secondary meaning of the verb ‘concern’ itself. If you can say, “These pictures trouble me” and turn that into, “These pictures are troubling”, then you can also do the same with, “These pictures concern me” (in the sense that they disconcert you, not in the sense that they deal with you), turning it into, “These pictures are concerning”. Like you, though, I too would probably have raised an eyebrow and gone, “Huh?” if someone used the word in that way to me.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet Whoa! That's asking for trouble! "These pictures show me." "These pictures depict me." "These pictures really cost me." "Those pictures hide me." Different senses are not guaranteed to continue across word class boundaries (and I'd call these -ing forms participial adjectives) or even to more closely related word-forms. Compare the contrast between _This is a fine scheme_ with _He's a real schemer_.

Comment: ‘Concern’ and ‘trouble’ are semantically (almost) identical. Of course you can’t just randomly pick any transitive verb to fill in. My point was precisely that in the sense used by the asker’s daughter, ‘concerning’ is not the regular adjective ‘concerning’, but an ad-hoc adjective derived from the present participle of the verb. Such derivations are quite transparent, and they (unlike established derivations) _do_ bring along the sense of the source to the derivation.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Whether or not the sense is *guaranteed* to continue, in this case the sense *has* continued; I've encountered *concerning* in this sense since the mid-1990s. The possible collision of senses seems to be mitigated in use: I've heard this only as a predicate adjective, never as a preposed attributive.

Comment: @StoneyB: I've no problem with this sense of 'concerning' - I was querying the reasoning 'If you can say, “These pictures trouble me” and turn that into, “These pictures are troubling”, then you can also do the same with, “These pictures concern me”. Try 'If you can say, “These children are exhausting” and turn that into, “These children exhaust me”, then you can also do the same with, “These children are demanding”.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Fersher, it creates problems. But Google it and lo and behold: "Why do people have children when children are demanding and exhausting and expensive?" ... "children are demanding and mothers are dull: news at 11". The "reasoning" is followed by usage.

Comment: @StoneyB: '**you can also do the same with**, “These children are demanding” ' - if you did what I stated, you would get “These children demand me”. I'm saying that JBJ's logic is inaccurate (though it often seems to work, as with the 'concern' and 'trouble' transformations).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ah, I understand you now: you're saying the transformation is not reversible, which may be generally true. Fair enough, Google offers only four distinct instances of "children are demanding me" (though they all seem reasonably acceptable, e.g.: "Well the children are demanding me haha, so i'd better tend to them"), and that's arguably a different sense of *demand*, which would not translate into "demanding children". Maybe. Though I think probably the rule is "whatever can be done with language eventually will be". :)

Comment: @StoneyB: I'm actually saying that behaviours with related structures are not totally predictable (and thus are unpredictable). There may well be many examples that behave identically, but then an anomaly will be found. For instance, possessive 'have' doesn't passivise: John has a red car. *A red car is had by John.  'Own' _does_ partially: John owns the/a red car. The red car is owned by John. ?A red car is owned by John. Delexical 'have' doesn't passivise *A bath (etc) was had by John **except in** A good time was had by all.